# want to diplay ads from my database if ads not found than chitika code ads display

Tags: php, sql

This is my code. please add if else statement in this code. As if ads found in my database than ads display from database otherwise chitika code ads display. no this code display both ads first display ads from my database and then from chitika code ads. please add if else statement. because i have no idea how to apply if else in this matter.

```
<div style="margin-left:-7px ! important;">
<?php
            $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
            $query4 = $conn->query($sql4);
            $row4 = $query4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $link4 = $row4['link_url'];
            $images4 = $row4['imagepath'];
            $immg4 = basename($images4);
            $imagee4 = "adverts"."/".$immg4;
            $rowc = $query4->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($rowc>=1){
            echo "
            <a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4';></a>";
            }
            else {
            echo "";
            }
        ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
( function() {
if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
var unit =           {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"seeknfameads","width":300,"height":250,"sid":"Chitika Default","color_site_link":"337ab7","color_text":"337ab7"};
var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
}());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" async>  </script>
</div>
```

please write code again with if else. as i copy paste into my page. thanks in advance.

Comment: `rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`?  RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php  that method has no arguments.

Comment: just want to apply if else @Marc B

Comment: you already have an if/else... and we are not here to write code for you.

Comment: i know i have if else. on else section in echo statement how to add the below chitika script ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are asking how if/else works in php.

if else is used to execute some code when a statement is true and another one if it is false.

If you define a function to get the number of ads from your database and a function to display the ads from your database and a function to display the ads from Chikita then your code might look like this:

```
if(getNumberOfAdsInMyDB() > 0){
    displayAdsFromDatabase();
}
else {
    displayAdsFromChikita();
}
```

This will only execute the function `displayAdsFromDatabase()` if `getNumberOfAdsInMyDB()` returns a value that is bigger than 0 and will only execute the function `displayAdsFromChikita()` when `getNumberOfAdsInMyDB()` returns a value that is not bigger than 0.